# ExtJS Grid Reconfigure breaks gridfilters plugin

Tags: filter, grid, store, extjs5

I'm using Ext version "5.0.0.970". I have grid.reconfigure function for a grid which is using gridfilters plugin.
Without reconfigure, the plugin works fine but with Reconfgiure, there are several errors.
I fixed the Filter.js to use

```
me.store.destroy();
```

instead of

```
 me.store.destroyStore();
```

since that was throwing an error. 
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?283793-Grid-reconfigure-not-working

But now, i get a new error for Collection.js

```
TypeError: items is null
n = items.length,
```

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?289098-Problem-with-gridfilters-plugin&p=1104449